# Async Bash Script of Non Dependant Commands?

Tags: bash

I basically have 10 or so C++ files that I run via command line. I recently made a bash file that takes the parameters and runs all the C++ files. It is probably the most basic sh command one could make. That being said is it possible to make them run async? None of the scripts depend on each other and there is plenty of CPU and RAM to run all the scripts at once.

The Script

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "running script 1..."
./script1 $1 $2 $3 $4

echo "running script 2..."
./script2 $1 $2 $3 $4

echo "running script 3..."
./script3 $1 $2 $3 $4
```

Comment: Append a simple `&`?

Comment: Take a look at the `&` operator. It works exactly the same as `;`, but it forks the process into the background.

Comment: Also, you'll want to quote those variables: `"$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"`. You could also just change that to `./script1 "$@" &`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `&` after each command you want to background, and optionally `wait` to wait for them all:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "starting script 1..." 
# "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" "$3"...
./script1 "$@" &

echo "starting script 2..."
./script2 --misc-flag=foo "$@" &

echo "starting script 3..."
./script3 --foobar &

echo "Waiting for all scripts to finish"
wait
```

Or if all the scripts are invoked the same way with the same flags as in your example, use a loop:

```
#!/bin/sh
for script in ./script*
do
  echo "Starting $script..."
  "$script" "$@" &
done

echo "Waiting..."
wait
```

Comment: This worked great similar to what the other commenters said. So simple and awesome!

Comment: as a side note, if you actually only needed the first 4 arguments (as your script shows), you can change `"$@"` to `"${@:1:4}"`.